# Error when trying to get data from MySQL using EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework-core

I am writing a (hopefully) simple api that just pull some data from my MySql server. I'm writing the handler for pulling a list of all the data and it is giving me this error when I call the endpoint through Swagger

```
System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format.
 at MySqlConnector.Core.TextRow.GetValueCore(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, ColumnDefinitionPayload columnDefinition) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/TextRow.cs:line 58
 at MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetValue(Int32 ordinal) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/Row.cs:line 38
 at MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetGuid(Int32 ordinal) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/Row.cs:line 165
 at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 ordinal) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 236
 at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at ITSystemAPI.DataAccess.Repositories.AsyncListRepository`1.ListAsync(ISpecification`1 spec) in C:\Users\conne\source\repos\ITSystemAPI\ITSystemAPI.DataAccess\Repositories\AsyncListRepository.cs:line 22
```

I don't know if i'm just being a bit dim, but I can't see any of the "Identified items" in the error message

My handler currently does this:

`List<ClientAppInformationLocal> response = await _listDeviceLogInformationRepository.ListAsync(new ListDeviceInformationSourceAllSpec());`

This then takes it to my AsyncListRepository, which should be generic and be used by anything that wants to List data

```
  public async Task<List<T>> ListAsync(ISpecification<T> spec)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = this._dbContext.Set<T>();
        query = spec.Query(query);
        List<T> listAsync = await EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(query);
        return listAsync;
    }
```

However, it fails when trying to run `EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(query);`

Here is my table definition:

```
   public Guid MachineGuid { get; set; }
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public decimal CPUTemp { get; set; }
    public decimal FreeRam { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalRam { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoggedDateTime { get; set; }
    public int Active { get; set; }
```

Here it is in mysql
[image]

MySQL version is 8.0.21

Comment: Show column names, table definition, version of MySql. And probably it is better to create issue in MySqlConnector Github repository.

Comment: It looks like your code is calling `GetGuid` on a column that isn't `CHAR(36)`, or doesn't contain a value of the expected length.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i've updated my post

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I've looked through everything and every reference for putting the ID (the char(36)), it is Guid. It fails worse if i change it to string

Comment: Was the data inserted via EF, or are you reading an existing database with an EF app? How does it "fail worse" if you're reading strings? Are there `NULL`s in the column?

Comment: The data was existing already in the DB. This is just an EF Api to pull the data and serve as json. It fails specifically to the MachineID if I change that to String rather than Guid. There should be no nulls in that column as its a primary key

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Oh god there was a null in there! It must have been inserted before I made that column a primary key, what a dope I am. I just ran it with that record removed and it gave me a different error message in regards to mapping, I should be able to work through that one. Cheers for your help

Comment: It might work if you changed your mapping to `Guid?`, then? That should cause EF to check for `NULL`s first, without just assuming everything is non-NULL.